# I am trying mule training walkthrough 6-3 and getting a different output

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

This is an example walkthrough in 6-3 of mule 4 developer training. I am getting different output when using Advanced Rest Client (ARC)

Can anyone please help me resolve this problem.

Below is the configuration XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="7afe9f88-0f1f-4a25-9c3f-572e417bd4a4" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="a965e1e5-26d7-49c1-9eb4-b169b18ff64f" >
        <http:request-connection host="localhost" port="8081" />
    </http:request-config>
    <flow name="helloFlow" doc:id="d8e8afa2-238a-4dc5-9a43-96a932422a2a" >
        <http:listener doc:name="GET /hello" doc:id="86b90724-ca42-46ee-bc40-41204f6a2f7f" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/hello" allowedMethods="GET">
            <http:response reasonPhrase="Success">
                <http:headers ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    "name" : "Max"
}]]]></http:headers>
            </http:response>
        </http:listener>
        <set-payload value="Hello World" doc:name="Hello" doc:id="c9c362cb-8d96-4a66-bdcf-91ce611cffbd" />
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="GET /goodbye" doc:id="a2eab23f-42d2-4fef-94ea-c170364c5e27" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/goodbye" responseTimeout="300000" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="5f813a3c-9af8-4131-a1ec-2947e301ba90" />
    </flow>
    <flow name="apdev-examplesFlow" doc:id="06c419b2-f71e-4711-8d3c-4585b15fd8ed" >
        <http:listener doc:name="GET /goodbyeFlow" doc:id="60dc16f6-47d5-460b-a471-4567ac7ec0d0" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/goodbye" allowedMethods="GET"/>
        <set-payload value="Goodbye Mulesoft" doc:name="Goodbye" doc:id="df40f379-5a7b-4556-abeb-7919863af9ec" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="39f101bc-f33b-4fdc-b66c-032455f6d0af" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Expected Output

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1azC.png)

Obtained Output

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1WL8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see the response headers in ARC - Click on the 'Details' link on the far right(its on the same line as 200 status code'

Also the body is different because you have 'Goodbye Mulesoft' instead of 'Goodbye' in set-payload:

```
<set-payload value="Goodbye Mulesoft" doc:name="Goodbye" doc:id="df40f379-5a7b-4556-abeb-7919863af9ec" />
```

Change to:

```
<set-payload value="Goodbye" doc:name="Goodbye" doc:id="df40f379-5a7b-4556-abeb-7919863af9ec" />
```

This will make your content-length headers match also.